# PDF file not opening in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, browser

I have an uploading facility in my website. But when i try to open the uploaded pdf file, its not opening. In chrome its showing as a black page. But when i checked the link in Internet Explorer the pdf file is opening properly.

The following is the link:

http://www.rainbowctm.com/images/customer/e42a3ed0-b57a-11e8-abff-09dce1b47db7/pdf-sample.pdf

This file link is opening in Internet Explorer but not in chrome. Can anyone guide me if on what the problem is. Help appreciated.

Comment: Open in firefox and check the error "The image “http://www.rainbowctm.com/images/customer/e42a3ed0-b57a-11e8-abff-09dce1b47db7/pdf-sample.pdf” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

Comment: Check html of http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf, I think you are using img tag to load pdf.

Comment: How to use PDF in html page: https://www.codexworld.com/embed-pdf-document-file-in-html-web-page/

Comment: Yes i am using image tage to load the pdf file. Guess thats the mistake i am doing.

Comment: How can i check the html of africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

Comment: Right-click, inspect, check html source code, this would be good starting point: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/